# Using nvprof to Count CUDA Kernel Executions

Tags: cuda, nvprof

Is it possible to use `nvprof` to count the number of CUDA kernel executions (ie how many kernels are launched)?

Right now when I run nprof what I am seeing is:

```
==537== Profiling application: python tf.py
==537== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 51.73%  91.294us        20  4.5640us  4.1280us  6.1760us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
 43.72%  77.148us        20  3.8570us  3.5840us  4.7030us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
  4.55%  8.0320us         1  8.0320us  8.0320us  8.0320us  [CUDA memset]

==537== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 90.17%  110.11ms         1  110.11ms  110.11ms  110.11ms  cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain
  6.63%  8.0905ms         1  8.0905ms  8.0905ms  8.0905ms  cuMemAlloc
  0.57%  700.41us         2  350.21us  346.89us  353.52us  cuMemGetInfo
  0.55%  670.28us         1  670.28us  670.28us  670.28us  cuMemHostAlloc
  0.28%  347.01us         1  347.01us  347.01us  347.01us  cuDeviceTotalMem
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. In case you're not aware, there is both [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview) and command-line help available (`nvprof --help`).

What you're asking for is provided by the simplest usage of nvprof:

nvprof ./my_application

this will output (among other things) a list of kernels by name, how many times each one was launched, and what percentage of overall GPU usage each one accounted for.

Here's an example:

```
$ nvprof ./t1288
==12904== NVPROF is profiling process 12904, command: ./t1288
addr@host: 0x402add
addr@device: 0x8
run on device
func_A is correctly invoked!
run on host
func_A is correctly invoked!
==12904== Profiling application: ./t1288
==12904== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 98.93%  195.28us         1  195.28us  195.28us  195.28us  run_on_device(Parameters*)
  1.07%  2.1120us         1  2.1120us  2.1120us  2.1120us  assign_func_pointer(Parameters*)

==12904== Unified Memory profiling result:
Device "Tesla K20Xm (0)"
   Count  Avg Size  Min Size  Max Size  Total Size  Total Time  Name
       1  4.0000KB  4.0000KB  4.0000KB  4.000000KB  3.136000us  Host To Device
       6  32.000KB  4.0000KB  60.000KB  192.0000KB  34.20800us  Device To Host
Total CPU Page faults: 3

==12904== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 98.08%  321.35ms         1  321.35ms  321.35ms  321.35ms  cudaMallocManaged
  0.93%  3.0613ms       364  8.4100us     278ns  286.84us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.42%  1.3626ms         4  340.65us  331.12us  355.60us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.38%  1.2391ms         2  619.57us  113.13us  1.1260ms  cudaLaunch
  0.08%  251.20us         4  62.798us  57.985us  70.827us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.08%  246.55us         2  123.27us  21.343us  225.20us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
  0.03%  98.950us         1  98.950us  98.950us  98.950us  cudaFree
  0.00%  8.9820us        12     748ns     278ns  2.2670us  cuDeviceGet
  0.00%  6.0260us         2  3.0130us     613ns  5.4130us  cudaSetupArgument
  0.00%  5.7190us         3  1.9060us     490ns  4.1130us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%  5.2370us         2  2.6180us  1.2100us  4.0270us  cudaConfigureCall
$
```

In the above example `run_on_device` and `assign_func_pointer` are the kernel names.  There is also example output in the documentation I linked.

Comment: I updated the question with what I am seeing when running nprof. I don't see anything called out as a kernel.

Comment: I can think of two possibilities: 1. Your python code is not making any (successful) kernel calls - are you doing proper error checking?  Do you know for sure that kernels are being called?  2. You may need to tell nvprof to profile child processes - how to do this is covered in the documentation I linked.  This will depend on what kind of work exactly you are issuing in your `tf.py` - probably tensorflow.

Comment: Okay, turns out no kernels were being called.